# Nginx Rewrite permanent

Tags: redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

As was previously

```
/movies/the-last-song.html
```

now what I have so:

```
/movie/the-last-song
```

Currently I am trying with this but does not work.

```
rewrite  ^/movies/(.*)$.html  /movie/$1  permanent;
```

I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `$` sign in your regular expression. It stands for *end of line*, so the `.html` will never be matched. You should also escape the `.` as `\.`.

```
rewrite  ^/movies/(.*)\.html  /movie/$1  permanent;
```